# Remove ReGex matches from string php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove all of the CONSTRAINTS from a SHOW CREATE query in MySQL.

Here is and example of a query (I've added line breaks for ease of reading):

```
CREATE TABLE `x2_action_meta_data` ( 
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`actionId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
`eventSubtype` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`eventStatus` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`etag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
`remoteCalendarUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
`remoteSource` int(11) DEFAULT '0', 
`emailImapUid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
`emailInboxId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
`emailUidValidity` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
`emailFolderName` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), U
NIQUE KEY `emailImapUid` (
`emailImapUid`,`emailInboxId`,`emailFolderName`,`emailUidValidity`
), KEY `actionId` (`actionId`)
, CONSTRAINT `x2_action_meta_data_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`actionId`) REFERENCES `x2_actions` (`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The part that I want to remove is:

```
, CONSTRAINT `x2_action_meta_data_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`actionId`) REFERENCES `x2_actions` (`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE )
```

I've tested this using RegExer and it seems to work: http://regexr.com/6fj2p

Here is my PHP code to remove it (assume $this_table is already populated with my query:

```
$this_table = preg_replace("/[ ]*,[ ]CONSTRAINT[ ]+.*?(?=[ ]ENGINE)/", "", $this_table);
```

**It is not removing the text from my query.**  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `\s` instead of spaces and have the dot match a newline `(?s)\s*,\sCONSTRAINT[ ]+.*?(?=\sENGINE)` https://regex101.com/r/ebSCWO/1

Comment: You need the `s` modifier and I would use `\h` rather than `[ ]`. https://regex101.com/r/vDs99A/1 (or `\s` as noted above)

Comment: There is no space before `ENGINE`, so it matches nothing, just remove `[ ]`.

Comment: Alright, so I found the issue....when i use: /(?s)\s*,\sCONSTRAINT\s+.*?(?=ENGINE)/ preg_replace fails. But, when I use (without "," and leading space): /(?s)\s*CONSTRAINT\s+.*?(?=ENGINE)/, it works. The problem is that i have to remove the comma or the subsequent query fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works fine on the original query, before you added line breaks. But I think you should keep the last closing parenthesis `)` just before `ENGINE`, because it matches with the very first `CREATE TABLE (` opening parenthesis. To achieve that and make the regex work with or without added line breaks, try this:

```php
$this_table = preg_replace("/,\s+CONSTRAINT\s+.*?(?=\)\s*ENGINE)/s", "", $this_table);
```

The `s` [pattern modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) at the end of the regex ensures that a dot in the pattern also matches newlines.